# dft (discrete fourier transform) with C++ code

Tags: c++, fft, dft

I programmed c in Visual studio c++.

In visual studio c++, I operate complex number with `<complex>` at c code grammar, not c++.

`a[]` is 4001 array, so using `b[4001]` store operated value and finally return `a[]`.
`NXm` is defined 4001 from main.

when I compared with the result of matlab's fft, The difference occurs from the 169th to 4000th value.

Would you see if there is any error? or what is the cause?

Thank you for reading the question.

1. I've tried reversely progressing "for", from NXm to 0.
2. I've tried changing `double ak = (double)k * (double)n * (2.0 * M_PI / (double)NXm);`  to `double ak = k * n * (2.0 * M_PI / (double)NXm);`
3. When I've tried operating short length of field, function worked well.
   This is the code.

```cpp
void fft(complex<double> a[], int NXm)
{

    complex<double> sum = 0.0 + 0.0*I; ;
    complex<double> c = 1.0*I;
    complex<double> b[4001] = { 0 };
    for (int k = 0; k < NXm; k++)
    {   
        sum = 0.0 + 0.0*I;
        for (int n = 0; n < NXm; n++)
        {
            double ak = (double)k * (double)n * (2.0 * M_PI / (double)NXm);
            sum = sum + a[n] * exp(-c * ak);
        }
        b[k] = sum;

    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NXm; i++)
    {
        a[i] = b[i];
    }
}
```

I expect almost same result as fft of matlab.
Slight error of epsilon level is ok

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198457/discussion-on-question-by-ongpark-dft-discrete-fourier-transform-with-c-code).

Answer (score 0):

Complex exponential is:

```
exp(x + I*y) = exp(x) ( cos(y) + I*sin(y)) = exp(x) * cis(y)
```

problem may be caused by a flaw in FPU part of processor, if `y` is rather small, built-in a intrinsic function for `sin(y)` got precision worse than `|y - sin(y)|`. Naive implementations of Euler formula may err with small arguments, sloppy ones may assume that `sin(y)` is zero.

It's better to replace `sin()` by cosecant intrinsic, which is  a reciprocal sinus (1/sin(x)).

Another, less common issue is when trig functions are supplied by values which are greater than  `2*PI*n`, where `n` is a natural greater than 1.  Precision drops with increase of `n` and `sin (x) != sin(2*PI*n + x)`

Third, depending on compiler, there might be optimizing flags which regulate how compiler treats use of math functions and floating point math in general. They may default to imprecise but fast calculations. This may supercede with use of  C header in C++ code.

Comment: Um...  I can't understand what do you actually mean ... :'( So sorry....  how can I separate `exp(-c*ak)`..? Really really sorry

Comment: @ongpark `c = x + Iy`. That's definition of complex number. x is real part, y is imaginary. In fact, `complex<double>` is a 2D vector with `double` as type of components. it got methods to get real and imaginary. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex

Comment: If I change like ` exp(-0.0)*(cos(ak) - sin(ak)*I)`, is that same with your intention???? Also, I can't understand your second suggestion..

Comment: @ongpark ugh.. did you even research what values are supplied to the functions?  And no, I don't know what you're thinking... `exp(-c*ak)` equals to  `exp(-ak*c.real())* (cos(-ak*c.imag()) + I*sin(-ak*c.imag()))` Note the `ak` is proportional to `n`.

Comment: um... I know `ak` is proportional to `n` ... and then..? I don't know how to fix it..

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB used FFT (Fast Fourier Transform) algorithm for computing DFT. It is both much faster (O(n log n) as opposed to O(n^2) with the direct method) and more stable numerically. So don't expect the same results as MATLAB makes.